# Android upstream FCM messages priority/force

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to set the priority of upstream FCM messages using their SDK? Sometimes my upstream FCM messages are not sent directly, and sometimes not at all.

Is it possible to force Android to send a upstream FCM message directly?

This is how I send messages:

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
String id = getMsgId();
RemoteMessage msg = new RemoteMessage.Builder("[my_key]@gcm.googleapis.com")
    .etMessageId(id)
    .addData("msg_type", "set_connect")
    .addData("connect", "1")
    .addData("uri", "")
    .build();
fm.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no `priority` parameter (or anything similar) for an Upstream Message.

For the *forcing* a message to send, AFAIK, there's no need to. The usual behavior of upstream messages are for it to simply send the message(s) as it possibly can.